# ios - loading dll from the browser

Tags: javascript, ios

I saw in another thread that one can open an app from the browser.
Is it possible to load a library and call it's functions from a script?

10xs,
Nahum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not use dll files for shared library code, but rather dylib files. (Like MacOS).  But that's sort of part of the story.  You can't just "call shared library" code -- you'd have to have an application that performs the actions you want.

If you create an application that has a webview component, there exists methods that allow you to interact with the core OS from the webview, but only in a custom application -- not from a stock standard webpage loaded in mobile Safari.

Comment: 10xs, can I interact with the app using script?

Comment: You can build an app that has a webview that allows you to access that application using javascript. You can also build an app just in JavaScript -- look at the Phonegap project.

Comment: Take a look at PhoneGap (http://phonegap.com/) if you want to build an app that is mostly a web page but requires IOS services.

Answer (score 0):

DLL, Dynamic Link Library, is a Microsoft technology and associated with Windows. As far as I am aware, there exists no DLLs on iOS.